# Is a point to point wifi bridge capable of handling two subnets/buildings?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-bridge

I'm sorry for the convoluted title... I'm really not sure how to word it.

I have two buildings roughly 200' apart with clear line of site.  I had an Engenius WAP ([ENS200EXT](https://www.engeniustech.com/products/discontinued-eol/business/ens200ext.html)) with an omnidirectional antenna and an Engenius wireless bridge with a directional antenna ([ENS200](https://www.engeniustech.com/products/discontinued-eol/business/ens200.html)).  I put the WAP on my house and the bridge on the carriage house and pointed it at the WAP.  That link seems solid to me, as a speed test shows 55/14 Mbps (down/up) Internet at both locations and a LAN speed test comes in at around 80/80 Mbps (I think that's consistent with the 150Mbps rated link).

But... I then went and bought a brand new Ubiquiti Networks [Unifi AP AC Lite](https://www.ubnt.com/unifi/unifi-ap-ac-lite/) wireless access point and connected it to the bridge and the performance is horrible.  The max I can pull is about 25/14 but that's not really the story... the issue is constant drop-outs, hesitations, etc.  The Xbox gets kicked, movies stutter, etc.  Even at 25 it should handle it so something's not right.  That had me thinking perhaps my assumption that a "solid" link between the buildings is sufficient isn't correct.  Or is the WAP just that bad?  Even being 5 to 10 feet away in the same room is pretty spotty.  At the furthest corner a speed test will show about 3/1 but simple webpages will fail to load.

Ideas?

PS. 2.4ghz bridge is on channel 11 and the unifi is on channel 4, chosen after conducting a site survey.

Update: Did some practical tests. Playing on the Xbox revealed zero packet loss but frequent sustained periods of 2 to 4 seconds of 400ms ping (or more, that is the max it shows). Downloading a large file on a PC was similar with frequent stalls. Upload, however, was fine.  Netflix was mostly OK but had one "network failure" message.  The AP stats show zero packets lost through it all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the 2.4GHz radio of your new UniFi AP is interfering with the 2.4GHz point-to-point link that your EnGenius products are making. Try turning off the 2.4GHz radio on the UniFi AP and see if that fixes things. Also make sure your UniFi AP is positioned at least 2 meters from the EnGenius bridge, so that any out-of-band harmonics from its 5GHz radio won't interfere with the EnGenius bridge.

Comment: Putting both on different channels should be sufficient if there isn't any APs around. Out-of-band spurious emissions would really be bad luck! That's the kind of compulsory physical tests made for the WiFi Alliance certification.

Comment: See my PS and edit. I don't think that is the problem but I will try shutting down the 2.4 and see if the 5 is solid.